# How to trigger widget with custom intent?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I'm trying to trigger my widget with custom intents using google assistant prompt, but the widget didn't show up even after i pass an exact query, Something like "Get Balance on MyApp".

- The Widget showing correctly when i tried to use Google App Action
  Tools and run the custom intent preview.
- This problem not occur when i'm using a Common BII for my
  shortcut.xml capability.

Here's my Shortcut.xml

```
<capability
        android:name="custom.actions.intent.GET_BALANCE"
        app:queryPatterns="@array/GetBalanceQueries">
        <app-widget
            android:targetClass="com.mypackagename.bankapp.widget.BalanceWidgetProvider"
            android:targetPackage="com.mypackagename.bankapp">

            <extra
                android:name="hasTts"
                android:value="true" />
        </app-widget>
        
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.mypackagename.widget.BalanceWidgetProvider">
        </intent>
</capability>
```

Manifest

```
<!--widget-->
        <receiver
            android:name=".ui.widget.BalanceWidgetProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/balance_widget" />
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".ui.widget.BalanceWidgetProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.assistant.appactions.widgets.PIN_APP_WIDGET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.assistant.appactions:widgets:0.0.1'
```

Sample Query

```
<string-array name="GetBalanceQueries">
        <item>get account balance</item>
        <item>get balance</item>
        <item>get portfolio</item>
        <item>check balance</item>
        <item>check portfolio</item>
        <item>show balance</item>
        <item>show portfolio</item>
        <item>show my money</item>
        <item>show money</item>
        <item>show money report</item>
        <item>show funds</item>
        <item>show fund report</item>
        <item>show portfolio</item>
    </string-array>
```